# php-fpm and nginx super fast and timeout responses together

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm having some problem with my server:

```
Ubuntu 12.04
nginx 1.4.6
2GB RAM
OpenVZ VPS
```

I increased php-fpm settings as the default one was very low. To something like this:

```
pm.max_children = 48
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 100
```

and I got super fast responses but 4 out of 10 times, when I click on a link, it times out or get a very late response. If it is working and seems to be one of those long ones and I click on it again, I may get a fast response or one of those delays again.

Anyway, I reduced the number of servers to something like this:

```
pm.max_children = 48
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 100
```

and now the server is working OK. I don't get a super fast response, but all connections are good and reasonable. I get responses in 1 second max.

I don't think those first numbers are high for my machine. (this is now the current situation with the site working)

```
total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2048        604       1443          0          0        112
-/+ buffers/cache:        491       1556
Swap:          256          0        256
```

When it was acting weird, I remember "-/+ buffers/cache" row was about the same but the first row "Mem", was showing like 1600 used.

There's only ONE website on this server which at its busy hours gets 60-90 visits in 15 minutes period. (hardly 30 requests at the same time?)

I'm curious why higher numbers which seem to have no problem with my server resources, causes such behaviour. Also I'd like to get those super fast responses.

This is my nginx config if someone is interested. (removed the unnecessary lines like document root and which port it is listening etc etc)

```
user www-data www-data;
worker_processes  2;

events
{
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http
{


    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #access_log off;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     off;
    keepalive_timeout  5;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    server_tokens off;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server
    {
            location ~ \.php$
            {
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }

     }
}
```

Comment: Go back to the default php-fpm settings. You don't have enough traffic to justify raising it without reason.

Comment: It is a fast growing website and I think this is good thing that happened. Because even if I go back and later on I want to upgrade I may bump into this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you validated that you backend server which listens 9000 and it is responding timely manner? if not tweak it your backend server.
have you looked at timeout params ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561946/how-do-i-prevent-a-gateway-timeout-with-fastcgi-on-nginx

Otherwise, Enable debug option in nginx and refer log files for some clue. http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html